# How to inherit site role permissions from users groups to their members in Liferay 6.1?

Tags: inheritance, liferay, liferay-6, user-permissions

I'm using Liferay 6.1 and I have a user group, called MySite Approvers and assigned to it the site role Site Approver for the site MySite.

I would expect that the users belonging to this user group would have also the Site Approver role for MySite inherited, aka this site role's permissions inherited.

But the users do not inherit the site role permissions and in site memberships of MySite in control panel, users site roles are empty.

How could I fix it? Should I write a hook adding periodically the site roles to the members of user groups with site roles?

Comment: Would you mind using a Regular Role instead of a Site Role ?

Comment: @yannicuLar Yes, I need the site role functionality not the regular role. Assigning a user to the group "MySite Approvers" should give Site Approver functionality to the user for the specific site.

Comment: And "Site Approver" is a custom site Role you have created, right ?

Comment: Right, it is a custom site role.

Comment: Μαρία, are you sure you can't use a Regular Role? You can port the "Site Approver" role to a Regular Role, and assign it to the "MySite Approvers" UserGroup. I think this should work just fine for you.

Comment: as long as you only let users from that specific Site to join this userGroup.

Comment: But then those users would be site approvers for all my sites, which is something different from the requirements of my portal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54530/discussion-between-yannicular-and-maria-ioannidou).

Answer (score 0):

Liferay doesn't display your site role "Site Approver" in employee roles profile as the role is not associated to individual user but its assigned at user group.

However, User should be given with permissions as defined in "Site Approver" as long as User is member of your user group "MySite Approvers".

Liferay documentation [link here](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/creating-process-definitions) says:

> This is where portal users with the proper role review the content and
>   decide to reject it (move it back to the beginning) or accept it
>   (transition it to the next step).

So, for workflow, its important to have a direct role association to user. Not some kind of permission associated with user.

I guess this is the way functionality been designed. Doesn't sound to me as a bug as workflow doesn't expect any permission but expects user to be member of role.

Comment: OK, the first part makes sense, in order to separate the individual membership of a user to a site role from user's membership via user's group.

But as for the permissions user is not given, for example I had an approver workflow definition using site approver role. This does not take into account user groups membership to site roles.

May be this is a bug of the workflow module only then. I can further test other permissions too to see if they respect the roles inheritance from user groups.

Comment: Updated answer above as per above comment.

Comment: But user is indirectly member of the role site approvers via user's membership to a user group associated with the site role.

I think that mporting users and user groups from LDAP and associating the user groups to site roles should work seamlessly in all cases, even workflow and not require manual association of each user to a site role.
If this works with the rest of the authorization mechanism cases, I would expect to work for the workflows too.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work like that. You may put query in liferay forum as well for different views.

Comment: To my opinion this is rather a bug, as even if workflow expects a user to be member of a role, this should check indirect membership too. Else, LDAP imported user groups and site roles functionality could not work automatically, without administrators having to re-assign site roles to specific users directly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, trying to inherit an **Organization Role**, through every registered Portal User. After lots of testing I realized that only Regular Roles would get propagated, and behave as expected with PermissionChecker and RoleLocalServiceUtil.

If you try to create a **Regular Role**, instead of a Site Role, you can assign that role to a User, A UserGroup, an Organization or a Site
[image]
I still haven't find a complete documentation on the difference between Regular, Organization and Site Roles, but I'm getting the impression that e.g a Site role is not a Role you'll assign to all the users of a Site

Update: I opened the source for liferay 6.1.0 and noticed on the the docs of 
**RoleLocalServiceUtil.hasUserRole**

```
/**
* Returns <code>true</code> if the user is associated with the named
* regular role.
*
* @param userId the primary key of the user
* @param companyId the primary key of the company
* @param name the name of the role
* @param inherited whether to include the user's inherited roles in the
search
* @return <code>true</code> if the user is associated with the regular
role; <code>false</code> otherwise
* @throws PortalException if a role with the name could not be found in the
company or if a default user for the company could not be found
* @throws SystemException if a system exception occurred
*/
public static boolean hasUserRole(long userId, long companyId,
    java.lang.String name, boolean inherited)
    throws com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.PortalException,
        com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException {
    return getService().hasUserRole(userId, companyId, name, inherited);
}
```

Notice the  "**regular** role"

Now I don't have the time to check all the references back to this function, but for me it's a clear indication that the Role/Permission Checking mechanism of Liferay, MIGHT not be meant to work with *any* Role Type

Comment: The other two types of roles are as their name indicates organization and site scoped respectively. I think that the scoping of their permissions works fine, what seems not to work in some cases is the propagation of the permissions from user group's site role permissions to its members.

I have used regular roles as well for portal scoped permissions but I also need the site roles for site specific permissions. As I have in my LDAP user groups per site.

Comment: What I'm trying to say, is that Site and Orgnanization Roles don't work as their names indicate. Think about it : You can assign a Site to a Regular Role, But you can't select a Site for a Site Role.

Comment: In Liferay 6.1 what you can do is assign a site role for a user to a site. This is not a regural role. Regular roles are portal-wide roles. This works properly.

What seems not to work is when assigning a site role to a user groups, and this site role is part of a workflow configuration, the permissions are not propagated.

Comment: Well, looks like the UserGroup to SiteRole assignment is not propagated in your case. I understand your point, but I'm afraid I can't propose a 'clean' solution on this, other than making some workaround

Comment: OK, understood. Then I will try to fix it with a hook adding periodically the site roles to the members of user groups with site roles. Thank you for all the suggestions.

Comment: Personally, I'd try to avoid hooks, especially if an LDAP binding was involved. But this solution looks clean, so you could definitely try that.. Good Luck!